# How to apply material-ui styles for TextFields

Tags: react-admin

How can i change the syle of the reat react-admin's TextField to have the same style of material-ui's Outlined textFields :

https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#outlined

Thanks

Comment: please provide your current code. Did you try to set the variant as a prop?          `variant="outlined"`

Comment: yes i tried and i get the error : Failed prop type: Invalid prop `variant` of value `outlined` supplied to `Typography`

Comment: In the errors it says Typography which is a bit weird. Can you update your question with the snippet used for the TextField?

Comment: It is because the react-admin's TextField is based on Typograpy.

Comment: did you try using a `TextInput`?

Comment: I found the issue, it's because react-admin is based on a old version of material-ui with no variants !

Comment: nice, happy that you found the reason